# Access Denied running "Hello World" program through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new to Java and Eclipse, and am having trouble.

I wrote the basic Hello World program in Notepad and after some struggle managed to execute it through Command Prompt. In the training program I am doing, I am now suggested to run Hello World through Eclipse. Here is my code in Eclipse:

```
package program091220;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

This exactly matches the code in the training video I am watching, besides for a different package name. In the video when the host runs the program it gives the "Hello World" string in the console. When I run the program, I get the following message:

> 'Launching Hello World' has encountered a problem. Exception occurred
> executing command line.

There is an option to view details. The details are:

> Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop\Coding\Eclipse\eclipse\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\javaw.exe"
> (in directory "C:\Users\Spiralgo\eclipse-workspace\September 12
> 2020"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

I previously ran into the "Access is denied" error when trying to run through Command Prompt, a problem I solved by giving very specific folder location information when executing the program. I'm not sure how or if I can give specific folder information within Eclipse if the code is already within Eclipse itself? I'm still learning what Eclipse even is as an IDE.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have windows 10?

Comment: This feels like a permission problem, like Java was not installed with proper permissions to give it execute permission, or maybe you installed it to a different "user" on your system and didn't install it for "all users."  You may have to uninstall Java, then try again, watch carefully to what questions it asks you during installation.  Make sure to not skip steps and install for "all users."

Comment: Close Eclipse, delete the `eclipse-workspace` folder, restart Eclipse and re-create the project, *without* doing any folder permission manipulation. Don't copy anything from your command prompt testing, just enter the code in the Eclipse editor.

Comment: Yes, I have Windows 10. Andreas. I'm going to try your suggestion first, because it seems fastest. If it doesn't work, markspace, I'll try your suggestion second. I'll let you all know my results.

Comment: @Andreas I did a search within my "Eclipse" folder and there is no exact "eclipse-workspace" folder, though there are around 15-20 files within Eclipse with the word "workspace" in their name. Not sure what to delete. Is it possible "eclipse-workspace" is a folder that gets placed elsewhere in the computer, maybe in Program Files, when created? Or is there another possible name for the "eclipse-workspace" folder?

Comment: @Andreas Nevermind, the "eclipse-workspace" folder WAS getting created in a different location in the computer! Found it.

Comment: `C:\Users\Spiralgo\eclipse-workspace` <-- From the error message!! --- I believe `September 12 2020` was your project name?

Comment: @Andreas Okay, I deleted eclipse-workspace and re-created the code... And I got the same error message. markspace, I'll try your advice now.

Comment: @markspace (1/2) I uninstalled Java and re-downloaded it. Apparently it downloaded differently because a different set of programs were downloaded, seemingly more friendly for beginners (?) - a package of five programs "About Java", "Check for Updates", "Configure Java", "Get Help", and "Visit Java.com". I figured Configure Java was what I needed to work with to re-setup Java proper, but clicking on it gave the following error message:

Comment: @markspace (2/2)


---------------------------
Java Control Panel
---------------------------
Access is denied.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\javaw.exe" -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\..\lib\deploy.jar"  -Djava.locale.providers=HOST,JRE,SPI -Djdk.disableLastUsageTracking -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -Duser.home="C:\Users\Spiralgo"  com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel

Comment: @markspace Even clicking "About Java" gets the same error message! Access is denied! This is absolutely ridiculous in my opinion. 

And in this setup I didn't answer questions and I didn't skip steps, as far as I'm aware. This is where I downloaded from, clicking on the big red button:

https://www.java.com/en/download/win10.jsp

It can't get any more beginner friendly than this, can it? And yet I still get "Access is denied" everywhere. Who is denying me access-- Java or my computer itself?

Comment: I also tried running the programs "as Administrator", and got the same access is denied message.

Comment: Also, I can't start Eclipse now. The error message is over 1000 characters too long for this comment box. It's probably because I don't have a working copy of Java anymore.

You might wonder if what I had before was a working copy of Java, but I was at least able to execute Hello World! through Command Prompt.

Comment: The training video series I've been using gave a specific way of downloading Java that was different from the "easy" way I tried to do this time. I think I'm going to try to redownload Java the more complicated way the video did it.

I am worried, though, about potentially having multiple Java programs on my computer now, that might be interfering with each other? I have the original version I downloaded a month or two ago, I have the "easy" version I downloaded today that doesn't work at all, and now I'm going to download a third version the hard way again.

Comment: I am mentally exhausted and frustrated. I think I'm calling it quits for today.

Comment: When you download Java, where do you download from?  Can we have a link to the page you use?

Comment: @markspace Yeah. The second time I downloaded (after trying to delete per the recommendation here) was from this page: https://java.com/en/download/

Comment: New thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081800/consistent-access-is-denied-error-related-to-java