# Consistent "Access is denied" error related to Java

Tags: java, eclipse

The primary, direct issue right now is this: I can't open Eclipse anymore, and I can't seem to open Java, or execute Java codes-- all apparently in relation to an  "Access is denied." error.

The first sign of this problem was when I tried to execute Hello World through Command Prompt. Following the instructions exactly in a video, when I attempted the apparent executing command code:

C:\Programs>java Helloworld

...I would get the message "Access is denied". After much troubleshooting, I found that if I gave the exact folder chain the program was in, I could get Hello World! to work. This looked like:

C:\Users\Spiralgo\Desktop\Coding>java HelloWorld

Ok, fair enough. But then it happened again in Eclipse. Following elsewhere in the video, there is the execution of the HelloWorld program directly in the Eclipse IDE. But when I followed the instructions exactly, I would get the following error:

CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.

The file location shouldn't be a problem here... Since the code was getting written directly in Eclipse. I asked for help here in an earlier thread and was recommended to (1) try rewriting the code in Eclipse and then (2) to delete and reinstall Java. Rewriting the code led to the same error, so I tried deleting Java, and then reinstalling it. Some problems associated with this:

1. I can't tell if Java was properly deleted or not. There are so many Java files that I'm not sure if I deleted the right one, and there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to catch all of them in one deletion. I noticed there is a Java uninstaller program, but I can't tell if using that is properly deleting Java, or if I need to go a step further and erase everything before re-downloading.
2. When using the Java Uninstaller, the program warns me that I already have an up-to-date version of Java, and that the program is meant to be used to get rid of out-of-date versions of Java.
3. I tried downloading Java online after I thought I had deleted it. I simply went for what seemed to be the easiest download possible, on this site: (https://java.com/en/) and going through the big red button. This is different from the more "complicated" method described in the original download instructions I used, but I figured if I was having issues related to beginners, it would be fine to try a simpler route. However, this method seemed to download a different series of programs onto my computer: a Java folder containing the programs "About Java", "Check for Updates", "Configure Java", "Get Help", and "Visit java.com".

And guess what... Trying to open "Configure Java" leads to an "Access is denied" error! Here is the full message:

---

### Java Control Panel

Access is denied.

### "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin\javaw.exe" -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin..\lib\deploy.jar"  -Djava.locale.providers=HOST,JRE,SPI -Djdk.disableLastUsageTracking -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -Duser.home="C:\Users\Spiralgo"  com.sun.deploy.panel.ControlPanel

And now Eclipse won't open. When clicking on it I get a very long message that begins with: "JVM terminated. Exit code=2".

So at this point I can't even tell if I have Java or not right now. I also don't know if all of this is related to the consistent "Access is denied" message related to Java, and whether that's related to using different Java versions, or if my computer itself has some inappropriate setting that restricts access to things.

You can read more about how this problem evolved from the previous thread: [Access Denied running "Hello World" program through Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972323/access-denied-running-hello-world-program-through-eclipse)

Comment: What changes have you been doing to your Windows machine?  Are you logging in as a different user?  Are you modifying anything in the `C:\Program Files` directory?

Comment: @stdunbar I always log in as the same user... I don't think I even have the option on starting up to choose a user, since I'm the only one. As for C:\Program Files, I try to touch that stuff as little as possible, though I have been moving things around related to trying to get Java to start. For instance, previously moving Java out of Program Files and into a more convenient coding file I created.

Comment: Previous question for those who are just joining in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972323/access-denied-running-hello-world-program-through-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment113317738_63972323 Something I forgot to mention earlier is that for development you need the JDK, start here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html However you should not be getting "Access Denied", you might head over to https://superuser.com/ and ask there, there must be a step we are missing.

Comment: @markspace Isn't JDK the same as Java? Anyway, I did try downloading JDK from here earlier today: (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) but despite downloading and clearly seeing a Java program in a folder, my computer can't find it: Eclipse won't open, and Command Prompt can't find java with java -version. I guess I'll try superuser. Thanks